# ng view angularJS and spring boot

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot

i have the problem that i have a 404 error when the the rout will load my file in the ng view but i don't find how to resolve that i am new in angularJS and spring

```
app.js
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    console
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller : "loginController",
        templateUrl : "/pages/login.html"
    })})
```

**controller**:

```
app.controller('loginController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.companies=null;
  $http.post('http://localhost:8080/').success(function(data) {
    $scope.companies = data;
    console.log(data);
  }).error(function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  });
})
```

**controller java**:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    Facade facade;
    @RequestMapping(value = Paths.Public.PATH_ALL_COMPANY, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody List<CompanyDto> allCompany() {
        return facade.allCompany();
    }
    @RequestMapping(value=Paths.Public.PATH_HOMEPAGE,method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getindexPage(){
        return "index";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value=Paths.User.PATH,method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getindexPageqs(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

app module:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [ 'ngRoute' ]); 
app.config(function($routeProvider) { 
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', { controller : "loginController", templateUrl : "/pages/login.html" })
    .when('/user', { controller : "UserHomeController", templateUrl : "pages/user.html" })
   .when('/admin', { controller : "AdminHomeController", templateUrl : "pages/admin.html" }
);
```

html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp"> 
  <script src="modul/angularJS-1.2.32/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<div ng-view></div>
```

Comment: can you post app module and html code

Comment: [code]var app = angular.module("myApp", [ 'ngRoute' ]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider.when('/', {
  controller : "loginController",
  templateUrl : "/pages/login.html"
 }).when('/user', {
  controller : "UserHomeController",
  templateUrl : "pages/user.html"
 }).when('/admin', {
  controller : "AdminHomeController",
  templateUrl : "pages/admin.html"
 })

Comment: <body ng-app="myApp">
 <script src="modul/angularJS-1.2.32/angular.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script> <div ng-view></div>

Answer (score 0):

templateUrl : "/pages/login.html" change to **templateUrl : "pages/login.html"**
**or **
if you are calling from href then use this 
**or **
if your login.html template in WEB-INF then it will not access.so put it in WebContent not in WEB-INF.